# I have faced CORS policy error .No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have faced this problem so many time. I require all the middleware in my backend server code but it good for sometimes and then occur, after sometimes it's again running on his own and again cors policy error occur. Please give me a solution . Here is my backend code...

```js
const express = require("express");
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
const cors = require("cors");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

//necessary middleware app.use(cors()); app.use(express.json());

function verifyJWT(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "unauthorized access" });
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).send({ message: "Forbidden access" });
    }
    console.log("decoded", decoded);
    req.decoded = decoded;
    next();
  });
}

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.nfrv0.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

console.log(uri);
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const fruitCollection = client.db("fruitsInventory").collection("fruit");

    //AUTH API
    app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
      const user = req.body;
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      });
      res.send({ accessToken });
    });

    //get data
    app.get("/inventory", async (req, res) => {
      const query = {};
      const cursor = fruitCollection.find(query);
      const result = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(result);
    });

    //get inventory id
    app.get("/inventory/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
      const result = await fruitCollection.findOne(query);
      res.send(result);
    });

    //get api with filter email
    app.get("/myitem", verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
      const decodeEmail = req.decoded.email;
      const email = req.query.email;

      if (email === decodeEmail) {
        const query = { email: email };
        const cursor = fruitCollection.find(query);
        const result = await cursor.toArray();
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        res.status(403).send({ message: "Forbidden Access" });
      }
    });

    //delete api
    app.delete("/myitem/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
      const result = await fruitCollection.deleteOne(query);
      res.send(result);
    });

    //post data
    app.post("/inventory", async (req, res) => {
      const newItem = req.body;
      const result = await fruitCollection.insertOne(newItem);
      res.send(result);
    });

    //update data for quantity
    app.put("/inventory/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      const updateQuantity = req.body;
      const filter = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
      const options = { upsert: true };
      const updateDoc = {
        $set: {
          quantity: updateQuantity.quantity,
        },
      };
      const result = await fruitCollection.updateOne(
        filter,
        updateDoc,
        options
      );
      res.send(result);
    });

    //delete item
    app.delete("/inventory/:id", async (req, res) => {
      const id = req.params.id;
      const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
      const result = await fruitCollection.deleteOne(query);
      res.send(result);
    });
  } finally {
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("fruits server is running");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server is connected on port", port);
});
```

Comment: If the middleware is _"necessary"_, why is it commented out?

Answer (score -1):

You must set the header of the Axios first because CORS means that you don't have access to origin resource API, so you need to setup the header of Axios first, you can follow this resource [CORS](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
```